# Assistance with SQL commands to get certain columns?

Tags: sql

I am trying to import some data from an excel file into my sql database.  I have written a function to select data from the excel file using sql statements. That part works perfectly fine but I am having difficulty writing the SQL statement since the table is not a standard format.

I basically have a situation like this:

[image]

Notice how there is a separation in how the data is listed between Plant and col1.

I want to SELECT the column name (from col1 to col6), the plant, vehicle, and date WHERE the category falls IN( category1, category2) and Vehicle = Vehicle A and plant IN(Plant1, Plant2)

I can do this in multiple steps or use my programming language for assistance but I want to contain as much as possible to just sql to make it more efficient.  I do already have a method to separate the data using only my programming language but it is very slow, being why I am trying to do this.

The expected output I am aiming for would be this:

[image]

Comment: Could you give a sample table with data and expected output wrt that?

Comment: @NuriTasdemir The image I provided is the sample table with data. I have added the image for the output I am trying to achieve

Comment: So the first row in your table is (null, null, category1, category2, category1, category3, category3, category2) ??

Comment: You said you want to select category falls IN( category1, category2) and in your output there is col5 which is category 3. I did not get what you are doing.

Comment: @NuriTasdemir It was just an example but I have updated my image..